# Error when getting the tab delimated data from the text file to 2 variables in python

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, nlp, formatting

I have a text file which has tab delimated data with 2 language translations as follows;

```
to the regimes   thanthrayanta
according to the anuwa
great    maha
situation    thathwaya
parabraman   parabrahman
two of the two   dwithwayan
on a matha
depends  randa
exist    pawathee
he   ohu
```

I am trying to get those data as follows,

```
 # Read the file and split into lines
 lines = open('old data/eng-sin.txt' % (lang1, lang2), encoding='utf-8').\
 read().strip().split('\n')
```

But when I run the code, I get an error as ;

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

As I searched the error I got an answer as the % used is depreciated and new way is to use .formate but still it doesn't solve the issue. Please help to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Anyway this wouldn't work since you can have spaces, so for example you would obtain `lang1` = 'to' and `lang2` = 'the' in the first line.

You could do something like this:

```
with open('old data/eng-sin.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = [ line.split('\t') for line in f ]
```